# Gather userinfo on registration with simplemembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to the SimpleMembership that comes with ASP.NET MVC 4. I've added some additional fields to the UserProfile table that works fine. The task I'm having problem with is that I want the user that registrate on the site to be able to write Email and and City also. But the WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount overload only takes 3 parameters. So I can't have:

`WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { Mobile = model.Mobile },  new { Email = model.Email, new { City= model.City, false);`

How does one usually go about this? is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, 
    new { Mobile = model.Mobile, Email = model.Email, City = model.City});
```